# How to use Basic HTTP Auth with REST webservice (Java+Jersey)?

Tags: rest, http-headers, jersey, http-authentication

I am a newbie to REST webservice and have just created my first webservice.
In my service the user can create profile via simple form giving his desired Username and password.

Now how to check user credentials when the user logs-in ??
I mean i have a simple form which validates user has logged in but how to validate user when he is to perform various profile operation of add/update/delete ??

For example:
In FB you sign-in and it stores a cookie which has your credentials and when you perform operations like "Post Status",message a friend...etc... it doesn't ask for your credentials anymore because it has a cookie in which your credentials are there and it just uses that cookie...

But in REST we dont use cookie ,so the next option is HTTP headers.
And i want to know how to send and recieve user credentials via HTTP header .i.e
`Basic HTTP Auth`

Comment: Do you need anymore feedback on this? If not and my answer was helpful to you, you might accept my post to this question. Greetz :)

Answer (score 29):

**Client Side**

To send the credentials to the API you use the HTTP `Authorization` header, specifying the credentials in a form of `Basic username:password`. The username:password String has to be encoded using an encoding scheme called [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). So an example header could look something like this:

```
Authorization: Basic d2lraTpwZWRpYQ==
```

As the rest specification states that the client-server communication should be stateless, you have to include the header with the credentials on every request. Normally you will use a session cookie on the client side to identify the user so that he does not have to enter his credentials on every request.

**Server Side**

To check the credentials inside your Jersey REST Service, you need to catch and intercept all the incoming requests. Jersey provides a concept called `ContainerRequestFilters` to do this. For example if you use Tomcat you could add filters of this type inside your servlet definition in your web.xml like this:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>your.package.BasicAuthFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The referenced class `BasicAuthFilter` needs to implement Jerseys `ContainerRequestFilter` interface and override the `public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request)` method. Inside the method you will basically do the following:

- fetch the Base64 encoded credentials from the Authorization header of the request
- decode them (i.e. using `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary()`)
- use your UserDao (or other datasource provider) to check if the credentials are valid
- return status code `401 Unauthorized` if the validation fails (i.e. `throw new WebApplicationException(Status.UNAUTHORIZED)`)
- if the credentials are valid, simply return the request in order to delegate it to the Jersey Resource that is responsible for handling it

You can find a very good example in [this](http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/jersey-jax-rs-implements-a-http-basic-auth-decoder/) blog post.

Comment: the example in the provided link works with JERSEY 1.x only. And it doesn't work with 2.X.

Comment: The linked blog post contains a link to an example for Jersey 2.x: https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/jersey-jax-rs-implements-a-http-basic-auth-decoder-for-2-x-branch/